# How can I check whether an array is null / empty?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `int` array which has no elements and I'm trying to check whether it's empty.

For example, why is the condition of the if-statement in the code below never true?

```
int[] k = new int[3];

if (k == null) {
    System.out.println(k.length);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more of the code please? The bit where the array is initialised would be useful to see.

Comment: I am not sure what your asking. Surelly to check if an array is null one would say (array == null)

Comment: Do you not want if (k != null)

Answer (score 265, accepted):

There's a key difference between a `null` array and an empty array. This is a test for `null`.

```
int arr[] = null;
if (arr == null) {
  System.out.println("array is null");
}
```

"Empty" here has no official meaning. I'm choosing to define empty as having 0 elements:

```
arr = new int[0];
if (arr.length == 0) {
  System.out.println("array is empty");
}
```

An alternative definition of "empty" is if all the elements are `null`:

```
Object arr[] = new Object[10];
boolean empty = true;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != null) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

or

```
Object arr[] = new Object[10];
boolean empty = true;
for (Object ob : arr) {
  if (ob != null) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: ups, the last snippet has `obj !- null`, probably meant to be `obj != null`

Comment: Don't forget about: org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.isEmpty(k)

Comment: Remember, === would not work. You must use == because `null` is of a different type.

Comment: Why someone would assign null to int array, if it's initialised with zeros by default? Only reference types are initialised with nulls.

Answer (score 146):

`ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(testArrayName)` from the package `org.apache.commons.lang3` ensures Array is not null or empty

Answer (score 30):

Method to check array for null or empty also is present on org.apache.commons.lang:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

ArrayUtils.isEmpty(array);
```

Answer (score 24):

Look at its length:

```
int[] i = ...;
if (i.length == 0) { } // no elements in the array
```

Though it's safer to check for null at the same time:

```
if (i == null || i.length == 0) { }
```

Comment: if you need to check for both null and length 0, it's important to check for null first as you have done, to avoid a possible null pointer error

Answer (score 4):

I am from .net background. However, java/c# are more/less same.

If you instantiate a non-primitive type (array in your case), it won't be null.
e.g. `int[] numbers = new int[3];`
In this case, the space is allocated & each of the element has a default value of 0.

It will be `null`, when you don't `new` it up.
e.g.

```
int[] numbers = null; // changed as per @Joachim's suggestion.
if (numbers == null)
{
   System.out.println("yes, it is null. Please new it up");
}
```

Comment: In Java that won't compile, because it will tell you that `numbers` has not been initialized yet. "Uninitialized" and `null` are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I will edit the post to have `int[] numbers` changed to `int[] numbers == null`; In c#, it is not the case.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8+ you achieve this with the help of streams allMatch method.

For primitive:

```
int[] k = new int[3];
Arrays.stream(k).allMatch(element -> element != 0)
```

For Object:

```
Objects[] k = new Objects[3];
Arrays.stream(k).allMatch(Objects::nonNull)
```

Answer (score 3):

An int array is initialised with zero so it won't actually ever contain nulls. Only arrays of Object's will contain null initially.

Comment: what if I have to check null for integer

Comment: You can't check for null with primitives such as int.

Comment: depends where you declared it, if as a class member, then yes it's get initialized with zeroes. but when declared locally inside a method, i believe it's another case... you have to assign an initial value yourself. i suppose. just a thought!

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to check that in spring framework then `isEmpty(Object[])` method in `ObjectUtils` class helps,

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable Object[] array) {
        return (array == null || array.length == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The point here very simply is that the variable k isn't null because it points to the array. It doesn't matter that the array itself is empty. The null test in your post would only evaluate to true if the variable k didn't point to anything.

Answer (score 2):

I tested as below. Hope it helps.

```
Integer[] integers1 = new Integer[10];
        System.out.println(integers1.length); //it has length 10 but it is empty. It is not null array
        for (Integer integer : integers1) {
            System.out.println(integer); //prints all 0s
        }

//But if I manually add 0 to any index, now even though array has all 0s elements
//still it is not empty
//        integers1[2] = 0;
        for (Integer integer : integers1) {
            System.out.println(integer); //Still it prints all 0s but it is not empty
            //but that manually added 0 is different
        }

//Even we manually add 0, still we need to treat it as null. This is semantic logic.

        Integer[] integers2 = new Integer[20];
        integers2 = null; //array is nullified
//        integers2[3] = null; //If I had int[] -- because it is priitive -- then I can't write this line. 
        if (integers2 == null) {
            System.out.println("null Array");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean empty() {
    boolean isEmpty = true;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] != 0) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (i != 0) {
        isEmpty = false;
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

This is as close as I got to checking if an int array is empty.
Although this will not work when the ints in the array are actually zero. It'll work for {1,2,3}, and it'll still return false if {2,0} but {0} will return true

Answer (score 0):

By 'empty array' most probably you meant length is 0.

```
if( array.length == 0 ) {
    // do something ...
}
```

But it's also worth to check first if the array ref is `null` or not before accessing it's property (e.g. `length`).

```
if( array != null ) {
   if( array.length == 0 ) {
      // do something ...
   }
}
```

And this become necessary if the array is a parameter to a method.

```
public boolean isEmpty( Object[] array ) throws Exception {
    if( array != null ) {
        if( array.length == 0 )
            return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("isEmpty(): Array ref is null");
    }
    return false;
}
```

The checking should be done in cascading way (not using `&&` i.e. `array != null && array.length == 0`) since the order of evaluation of the conditions depends on implementation of the compiler. If it is evaluating the `array.length == 0` condition first, it will ends with runtime error if `array` is null.

Answer (score -1):

An `int` array without elements is not necessarily `null`. It will only be `null` if it hasn't been allocated yet. See [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialhero.com/tutorial-76-java_arrays.php) for more information about Java arrays.

You can test the array's length:

```
void foo(int[] data)
{
  if(data.length == 0)
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that what you want is

```
int[] k = new int[3];

if (k != null) {  // Note, != and not == as above
    System.out.println(k.length);
}
```

You newed it up so it was never going to be null.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check whether there is any elements in the array by finding out its length, then put it into if-else statement to check whether it is null.

```
int[] k = new int[3];
if(k.length == 0)
{
//do something
}
```