# Checking if char is empty

Tags: java, c++, char, is-empty, isnullorempty

I have a small problem converting code from java to C++

I am trying to check if a 2d array is set ,this is my  java code

```
for(int area_y = y -1 ;area_y > 0 ;area_y--)
    {
        for(int area_x =  0 ;area_x < x; area_x++)
        {   
            if(area[area_x][area_y] == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(" "); // this is printed 
                                      //  if area[area_x][area_y] is not set 

            }
            else
            System.out.print(area[area_x][area_y]);


        }
            System.out.println();
    }
```

and this is my c++ code and this works

```
for(int area_y = y -1 ;area_y > 0 ;area_y--)
{
    for(int area_x =  0 ;area_x < x; area_x++)
    {   
        if(area[area_x][area_y] == 0) // this line does not work as
                                      // the next line is not executed
        {
            cout << "1";
        }
        else
        cout << (area[area_x][area_y]) ;                
    }

cout << endl;
}
```

The problem is with checking if that varaible is set, it is a `char area[20][50];`

how can I properly check if a variable is empty (not set) in c++ ?

Comment: Can you define what it means for a variable to be "empty"?

Comment: The characters are uninitialized with that declaration. You could always set them to 0.

Comment: try to declare char array as global or fill it with `0` as initialization

Comment: @NikBougalis with empty i mean not set

Comment: @user1951751, If you really want to distinguish between that, `boost::optional` is good.

Comment: @user1951751 you can't - set them to some value and check against that. 0 seems appropriate.

Comment: There is no way to check if they are not set. The best you can do is check whether they have a certain value.

Comment: it's a value type can't be empty or not set any more than an int can. Look for '\0' or some other flag value.

Comment: Make it a 3D array `a[][][]` and if `a[][][0] == 1` if its set and `a[][][1] = value`. :)

Comment: Also, you seem to be confusing not being set with having the value `0`.

Comment: @juanchopanza in java the value `0` would mean that the variable is empty if not set [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-we-check-for-null-array-in-java)

Comment: In java you can use `null`. In c++11 u have `nullptr`.

Comment: So what happens if you set a variable's value to `0`? How can you tell whether the variable is not set, or set to `0`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Good question :) ,it worked for my purouse as I didnt use `int` values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, objects of scalar types are not zero-initialized. They are default-initialized, which means the value they get at initialization is undefined.

In particular, the value is unlikely to be 0 for `char`s, `int`, etc., and definitely you shouldn't rely on it to have any particular value. If you want your array cells to be initialized to 0 before you start working with them, you have to initialize them manually.

If you come from a Java world, you might think this is an unnecessary bulk of work, but consider that you're working with C-style arrays, and C is not meant to sacrifice performance for programmer time. There are cases where an initialization to 0 would uselessly waste CPU time, and you don't want to pay for what you don't use.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check if a variable has been "set" or not. You can only check if it is equal to a specific value.

Your code in java seems to work because, in Java, all primitive data types that are created but not initialized are given a default value by the compiler. In the case of a char, it's '\u0000', which is equivalent to 0.

In c++ the values of these characters are undefined. If you want to have the same behavior, you'll need to explicitly set all of the characters to 0 before you do your check.

Comment: After struggling very much searching how to check if a char was set or not, I modified the condition according to your information and the Java code worked out! `myChar == 0` - this effectively returns `true` for when the `char myChar;` never received a value.