# how to check the string array is empty or null android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to java. Am unable to check for null. Could you enlighten me on this? 
I have string array which has no elements.

I tried this code

```
String[] k = new String[3];
if(k==null){
    System.out.println(k.length);
}
```

Comment: A better duplicate - [How can I check whether an array is null / empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*Very precisely*

```
if(k!=null && k.length>0){
    System.out.println(k.length);
}else
    System.out.println("Array is not initialized or empty");
```

`k!=null` would check `array` is not `null`. And `StringArray#length>0` would `return` it is not empty[you can also trim before check length which discard white spaces].

*Some related popular question* -

- [What is null in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java)
- [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java)

Answer (score 9):

There's a key difference between a `null` array and an empty array. This is a test for `null`.

```
int arr[] = null;
if (arr == null) {
  System.out.println("array is null");
}
```

"Empty" here has no official meaning. I'm choosing to define empty as having 0 elements:

```
arr = new int[0];
if (arr.length == 0) {
  System.out.println("array is empty");
}
```

An alternative definition of "empty" is if all the elements are `null`:

```
Object arr[] = new Object[10];
boolean empty = true;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] != null) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

or

```
Object arr[] = new Object[10];
boolean empty = true;
for (Object ob : arr) {
  if (ob != null) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369983/1218762)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (myArray == null)

   System.Console.WriteLine("array is not initialized");

else if (myArray.Length < 1)

   System.Console.WriteLine("array is empty");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String k[] = new String[3];

if(k.length == 0 ){

System.out.println("Null");
}
```

it will display null if there is no item in array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
```

**UPDATE**

Better solution is this one:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(str)
```

Comment: There is no 'isEmpty()' method for string arrays in java.