# How to check whether given string array returns null?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to check the condition whether string array gives value or null.

String function:

```
String rowData[] = (String[]) ArrayUtils.subarray(DataArray, startIndex,
                                         (startIndex + maxColumnCount));

if(rowData not null)
{

}
```

Value of data array is coming by:

```
String DataArray[] = request.getParameter("values").split(",");
```

What would be in if Condition?

Comment: What language is this, `C#` ? OK: Java - Thank you ;-))

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-we-check-for-null-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the  **length/size of the array is zero or not**

```
if(DataArray.length != 0)  //something similar to this
```

Comment: yes, but i wanted to check it with rowData, its working now.  Thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

The request parameter could not have been given and yield null.

```
String dataArrayParam = request.getParameter("values");
String[] dataArray = dataArrayParam == null?
    new String[0] : dataArrayParam.split(",");
```

In general it would be:

```
if (rowData != null) {
```

BTW. `String[]` is a more conventional notation, `String a[]` comes from C compatibility in the early days of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check

```
if(DataArray != null)
{
     String rowData[] = (String[]) ArrayUtils.subarray(DataArray, startIndex,
                                         (startIndex + maxColumnCount));

     if(rowData not null)
     {

     }
}
```