# Can anyone tell me why the java code does not go into the if statement

Tags: java

Hi guys I have written a code which will output the contents from a xml files located in different folders into a csv file. But when there are no xml files, I would like to return a print statement with "No files" found.

The issue is my code just refuses to go into the main if statement and always executes the else statement.

Below is my code.

```
public class XMLReadExtract {

    public void extract_XML_Data(String InputPath, File OutputPath, FileWriter fileWriter) throws Exception {

        String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";                                                   /* Delimiter used for csv */

        File root = new File(InputPath);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();                                                 /* To List all files in the Input Path */


        try{        
            if (list == null){
                System.out.println("No files to be read");
                return;
            }                                                                               // End of main If Statement
```

Comment: "why the java code does not go into the if statement?" - Well, this has usually something to do with the condition ....

Comment: well you need to ask your question **`clear`**, and send the part of the code that have the problem, not all of the code !

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. You've posted over 100 lines of code, most of which is irrelevant to the problem. Next, the documentation for `File.listFiles` explicitly says it will return a 0-element array if no files are found - it only returns null if the path doesn't exist or isn't a directory.

Comment: [How can I check whether an array is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-we-check-for-null-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your condition:

```
if (list == null || list.length == 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher, i used only 

if (list.length == 0)