# AS3 - What would the length of an array be if there is no elements?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have an array that is connected to an input text box called `myTextbox`. Let's call the array `myArray`. The code looks something like this:

`var myArray:Array = myTextbox.text.split("|");`

Later on, I have to get the length of `myArray`. If `myTextbox` was empty, what would be the length of `myArray`?

I am tracing the length, but it says 1 for when it's empty, and 1 for when it has one element. I believe that's an error. Could somebody please answer my question?

Comment: Check this out, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty

Answer (score 1):

> *"If `myTextbox` was empty, what would be the length of `myArray`"*?

Check the docs under String's [**`split`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split()) option:

> "If the delimiter parameter is **undefined**... 
>   The **entire string** is placed into the first element (`[0]`) of the returned array."

It's nice that the entire string is returned. Your confusion lies in dealing with *the returning of an **empty** string*. The array has a length of 1 because something was returned and put there, but if you check you think you find nothing since it's an empty string like `""`...

**Test 1:** (string with content)

```
myTextbox.text = "hello world";

var myArray:Array = myTextbox.text.split("|");

trace("myArray length       : " + myArray.length);
trace("myArray [0]          : " + myArray[0] );
trace("myArray [0] as Int   : " + int(myArray[0]) );
```

Which gives `"hello world"` as first element (at `[0]`), since no `"|"` exists in string as a delimiter...

```
myArray len        : 1
myArray [0]        : hello world
myArray [0] as Int : 0
```

**Test 2:** (empty string)

```
myTextbox.text = "";

var myArray:Array = myTextbox.text.split("|");

trace("myArray length       : " + myArray.length);
trace("myArray [0]          : " + myArray[0] );
trace("myArray [0] as Int   : " + int(myArray[0]) );
```

Which gives empty `""` as first element (at `[0]`), since no `"|"` exists in string as a delimiter, the **entire** empty (zero-length) string now sits at `[0]`...

```
myArray length      : 1
myArray [0]         : 
myArray [0] as Int  : 0
```