# How to check if array is null or if the array contents are null

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

What is the best way to check if array is `null` value or if the array contents are `null` in combination in 1 statement in Java 6:

```
if ((myArray[0] != null) || (myArray[1] != null) || (myArray!= null)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Put the `myArray != null` first, and you probably want to use `&&`.

Comment: Look at this related question: [How can I check whether an array is null / empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty). I cannot think of a way to do it in one concise statement in Java 6, but that question has some answers that show how to check (in more than one line).

Comment: the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty is split into a statement and another method. I need to be able to combine them both into 1 statement

Comment: Why are you still using Java 6? It's been unsupported for the last 3+ years when Oracle have stopped issuing security updates. You are opening yourself up to security loopholes.

Comment: Is the length of the array fixed? Or can it vary in length? If so, is there an upper limit on the length?

Comment: the length of the array is fixed

Comment: Then wouldn't @AndyTurner 's comment have done it already? `if (array == null || array[0] == null && array[1] == null) { // array is null or contains only nulls }`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, check if the array is not `null` itself. If the array is `null`, it makes no reason to iterate its elements since Java will throw the `NullPointerException` upon access to it:

```
if (myArray != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Then inside the body of the condition iterate through all its elements and check if one of them is `null`.

```
boolean hasNull = false;
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] == null) {
        hasNull = true;
        break; // to terminate the iteration since there is no need to iterate more
    } 
}
```

---

This one-line solution (thanks for the warning from @Napstablook). The condition is evaluated as `true` if the array itself is `null` or one of its element is `null`:

```
if !(myArray != null && myArray[0] != null && myArray[1] != null) { ... }
```

Be aware that the `&&` operator works that if the left side is evaluated as `false`, it stops evaluating the rest of the condition because it will not affect the result. The same does `||` but with `true`. However, I suggest you avoid this solution since the index might overflow. Better use the `for-loop` mentioned above.

Comment: OP wants to check if the array is null or all the elements in the array are null.  See post-  **or if the array contents are null**

Answer (score 2):

To have it check for any value, I'd use `allMatch`. It's also important to check for array != null first, otherwise you'll get an Exception if it is.

```
if (array == null || Arrays.stream(array).allMatch(Objects::isNull))
```

> Note that this won't work with java prior to version 8, OP edited his requirements after I posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if Array is null:

```
String array[] = null;
if (array == null) {
  System.out.println("array is null");
}
```

Check if array is Empty:

```
array = new int[0];
if (array.length == 0) {
  System.out.println("array is empty");
}
```

Check for null at the same time:

```
int[] array = ...;
if (array.length == 0) { } // no elements in the array

if (array == null || iarray.length == 0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (myArray == null || Arrays.stream(myArray).allMatch(element-> element==null)) {}
```

Edit- For java 6, I really don't see this happening in one line. You can try this if one line is not necessary

```
  boolean isNull = true;
    if(myArray==null){
        System.out.println("array is null");
    }else{
        for(Integer element: myArray){
            if(element!=null){
                System.out.println("array is not null");
                isNull=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isNull)
            System.out.println("Array is null");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for example this

```
boolean isNullOrContainsNull = array == null || Arrays.asList(array).contains(null);
```

checks in a line whether the array is null or contains null elements

If you want to check whether the array is null or empty or all elements are null take

```
boolean containsNothingUseful = array == null
        || array.length == 0
        || !new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array))
            .retainAll(Arrays.asList((String)null));
```

(assuming a `String[]` array)

Uses the [`Collection#retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method which returns true when there were other values present, i.e. the inverse of "containsOnly"

Using this one liner is actually fairly inefficient and one better uses a method like below which doesn't create lots of temporary objects and mutates collections etc.

```
public static boolean containsNothingUseful(String[] array) {
    if (array == null || array.length == 0)
        return true;
    for (String element : array) {
        if (element != null)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// ...
if (containsNothingUseful(myArray)) { .. }
```

Comment: This will return true if there is atleast one element in the array that is null. 
OP wants to check if all elements are null.

Comment: @Napstablook true, I've added a version for that too

Answer (score 0):

Instead Itreating Manullay the array, re use the existing collection for this case.

1. Convert Array Into List
2. Check Null is present in list or not using contains() method;

Please find the sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[3];

        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = null;
        array[2] = 2;

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(null));
    }
```

Comment: This has been proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742211/7653073) already, and it does not fulfill the Op's request. They want to know whether **all** entries are `null`, not **any** entries.