# How to check whether an array with a specific Index is empty?

Tags: java, arrays, int

I followed the points made in this thread, but I get the error "the operator is undefinded for the argument types[...]"

[How can I check whether an array is null / empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty#2369983)

My code:

```
public class Test{

private int[] array = new int [5];

  public int method(int i) {
      for(int s = 0; s <= array.length; s++) {
          if( array[s] != null) { //I get the error in here even though the highest upvoted answer in the linked question recommends this solution. I obviously cant check it for 0, because the user input can be 0.
            array[s] = i;
          } else {
             method(i);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `s <= array.length` is *always* wrong as you will try to access past the bounds of the array (causing an exception)

Comment: Also an `int[]` cannot have "empty" values in it - the default is 0, there is no way to set it to `null`. Either your array can be `null` or have a `length` of 0, there is nothing else you can do

Comment: Ur right, didnt think of that but even by fixing it with array.length -1 my other issue still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error as `int` is a primitive type. In your case `array[s]` returns an `int` not an `Integer`. `Int` can't be a `null`.

Change your array from `int[]` to `Integer[]` if you want to check null.

```
private Integer[] array = new Integer[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have array of `int` which is primitive type, primitive types in Java can't be `null` so compiler gives error when checking if it is `null`, if you really want it you can use `Integer` which is wrapper class for `int`.