# Empty integer array in java

Tags: java, arrays

> Write a function that takes an array as input and returns an array of 2 numbers. The returned array contains the sum of even numbers and sum of odd numbers from the input.
>
> If any of the input is null it should be treated as an empty array
>
> Example:
> Input:
> [30, 18, 2, 83, 20, 71]
> Output:
> [70, 154]
>
> Input:
> [14, 11, 10, 67, 41]
> Output:
> [24, 119]
>
> Input:
> [36, 24, -82, 29, 44, -3, -100, -5, 49]
> Output:
> [-78, 70]

The function that I have written is

```
public int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] input) {
        
        int x[] = input;
        int even = 0, odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] % 2 == 0)
                even += x[i];
            else
                odd += x[i];
        }
        int[] ans={even, odd};
        return ans;
    }
```

But how should I incorporate the part of the empty array?

Comment: What do you mean with "How should I incorporate the part of the empty array"?

Comment: What would be the reault of an empty array? How many elements can you sum up?

Comment: simplest: `if (input == null) return new int[2];` some better, just do the `for` `if (input != null)`  (Note: why do you need `x`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if any of the input is null it should be treated as an empty array

Why not just check for `null` value?

```
public int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] input) {
    int even = 0, odd = 0;
    if(null != input){
        for (int i: input) {
            if (0 == i % 2){
                even += i;
            } else{
                odd += i;
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[]{even, odd};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if `input` is `null` first. If it is, work on an empty array instead:

```
int x[] = input == null ? new int[0] : input;
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I think the result has always to have two elements: the sum of even and the sum of odd elements.

Comment: @LuCio it will. `x` is just the input to the summing functionality.

Comment: Ok ... i see ... it's not the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] input) {

        int x[] = input;
        int even = 0, odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if(x[i] != null)    //in case array contains elements which aren't null
        {
            if (x[i] % 2 == 0)
                even += x[i];
            else
                odd += x[i];
        }
        else   //in case the array has null array elements
        {
           even = 0;
           odd = 0;
        }
        int[] ans={even, odd};
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As you have stated here while checking if the array is empty, but the question says that if any of the elements is null then treat it as an empty array.

Comment: Did you try to compile that? `x[i]` has type `int` so it is a primitive type, not a reference. It cannot be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
public class Test {

public static int[] getSumOfEvensAndOdds(int[] input) {
    int[]   def = {0,0};

    if (input != null && input.length!=0) {
        int x[] = input;
        int even = 0, odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] % 2 == 0)
                even += x[i];
            else
                odd += x[i];
        }
        int[] ans = {even, odd};
        return ans;
    }

    return def;
}

public static void main(String [ ] args){
    int[]   ar = {10,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91};
    int[]   res;

    res = getSumOfEvensAndOdds(ar);
    System.out.println("Result: " + res[0] + " " + res[1]);

    int[]   ar2 = {};
    res = getSumOfEvensAndOdds(ar2);
    System.out.println("Result: " + res[0] + " " + res[1]);

    int[]   ar3 = null;
    res = getSumOfEvensAndOdds(ar3);
    System.out.println("Result: " + res[0] + " " + res[1]);
}
```

}

I use input!=null to check whether the array is null and input.length!=0 to check if its size is 0. Also, in the main method I give three examples.

Answer (score 0):

Empty array may be return like this `return new int[]{}`

Answer (score -1):

Your question is just about arrays being empty. A quick search got me this: [How can I check whether an array is null / empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty)