# How to exit a function with return type int[]?

Tags: java, arrays

I was doing a basic program of right rotation of array and for base condition, I wanted to exit the function with `return`. However, it is giving an error that type is not valid.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
import java.util.*;

public class RightRotationArray{
 public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
   if (K < 0 || K >= A.length) {
         return; // error showing here.
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
         int last = A[A.length - 1];
         for (int j = A.length - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
             A[j + 1] = A[j];
         }

     A[0] = last;
         
     }
     return A;
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty integer array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666751/empty-integer-array-in-java)

Comment: This tells you what you want to know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666751/empty-integer-array-in-java. But if I passed an array into a function that returned an empty array on an error condition, is I be pissed!

Comment: It is happening because you aren't returning an `int` array from a method that is supposed to return one. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 3):

you can (return null) or (return new int[]{}), but the best way is to throw an exception:

```
public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if (K < 0 || K >= A.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("K is invalid");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        int last = A[A.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(A, 0, A, 1, A.length - 2 + 1);

        A[0] = last;
    }
    return A;
}
```