# checking if array is empty without getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, priority-queue, binary-heap

I'm getting a NullPointerException error when I check if an array is empty. It should return null when the array is empty, but I cannot find why it's not working. Any hints on what I am doing wrong? Here's my entire code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class EventPriorityQueue {

    class Node {
        Event event;
        int priority;

        Node(Event event, int priority) {
            this.event = event;
            this.priority = priority;
        }
    }

    private int size;
    private Node[] array;

    public EventPriorityQueue() {
        this.size = 0;
        array = new Node[20];
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void insert(Event event, int priority) {
        if (size == 0) {
            array[0] = new Node(event, priority);
            size++;
            return;
        }
        if (size == array.length) {
            Node[] array2 = new Node[size*2];
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length);
            array = array2;
        }
        if (size > 0) {
            array[size] = new Node(event, priority);
            size++;
            percolateUp(size - 1);
        }
    }

    private void percolateUp(int index){
        int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
        while (array[index].priority < array[parentIndex].priority) {
            Node temp = array[parentIndex];
            array[parentIndex] = array[index];
            array[index] = temp;
            index = parentIndex;
            parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
        }
    }

    public Event peek() {
        return array[0].event;
    }

    public Event poll() {
        if (array[0] == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Node deletedElement = array[0];
        array[0] = array[size - 1];
        array[size - 1] = null;
        size--;
        percolateDown(0);
        return deletedElement.event;
    }

    private void percolateDown(int index) {
        int smallest = index;
        int rightChildIndex = (index * 2) + 2;
        int leftChildIndex = (index * 2) + 1;
        if (array[leftChildIndex] != null) {
            if (array[leftChildIndex].priority < array[smallest].priority) {
                smallest = leftChildIndex;
            }
        }
        if (array[rightChildIndex] != null) {
            if (array[rightChildIndex].priority < array[smallest].priority) {
                smallest = rightChildIndex;
            }
        }
        if (smallest != index) {
            Node temp = array[index];
            array[index] = array[smallest];
            array[smallest] = temp;
            index = smallest;
            percolateDown(smallest);
        }

    }

    public int[] toPrioritiesArray() {
        // DO NOT CHANGE THIS FUNCTION
        int[] result = new int[this.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            result[i] = this.array[i].priority;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean checkHeapProperty(int[] priorities) {
        for (int i = 0; i < priorities.length; i++) {
            if (2 * i + 1 < priorities.length && priorities[i] > priorities[2 * i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
            if (2 * i + 2 < priorities.length && priorities[i] > priorities[2 * i + 2]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize the queue
        EventPriorityQueue queue = new EventPriorityQueue();
        // add some numbers to the queue
        int NUM_EVENTS = 1;
        for (int i = NUM_EVENTS; i > 0; i--) {
            queue.insert(new Event(i), i);
            System.out.println("inserted " + i);
        }

        // poll everything
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_EVENTS + 1; i++) {
            int next = queue.poll().getTime();
            System.out.println("polled " + next);
        }

    }
}
```

I think my error is here:

```
public Event poll() {
    if (array[0] == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

Any hints/helps would be appreciated!!

Comment: That program logic is strange. You want to return `null` in `poll()` when an item in the array is null, ok, but way doesn't the method calling `poll()` bother to check if the returned value is `null` or not. It makes no sense to play with null when your code isn't able to deal with it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check whether an array is null / empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369967/how-can-i-check-whether-an-array-is-null-empty)

Comment: "Event poll() - returns and removes the next Event in the priority queue. Returns null if the queue is empty." This is a brief description of how `poll()` should work. Does my approach seem right?

Comment: Your `poll()` isn't the issue here. Something else in your code doesn't bother to check if the returned value is `null`, that's why you get the NullPointerException.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `int next = queue.poll().getTime();`. Really? `queue.poll()` can return `null`. You don't check for that. So it throws a NullPointerException. Happens, as expected. You could have saved the time of a lot of people if you had posted the actual stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question too much, however I think I see the issue, try this -

```java
public Event poll() {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Tom oh my gosh, I did not read the question correctly ;( I will edit it now, sorry.

Comment: Ok, since that is fixed, to the actual issue from OP, the NPE. How does your code fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_EVENTS + 1; i++) {
            int next = queue.poll().getTime();
            System.out.println("polled " + next);
        }
```

This loop is running twice. Please try removing `+ 1` . Then there will be no NullPointerException.

queue.poll() is null in 2nd iteration. So when you do getTime() on null. It throws NullPointerException.

Comment: I purposely added the `+ 1` to check if the code would properly return null when `poll()` is called on an empty array.

Comment: In that case you should check for if(queue.poll()!=null) and then do queue.poll().getTime();

Comment: array[0] == null gives you true because array is holding a null object.